# Extract Version Number from String

Tags: powershell

Using the following PowerShell command,

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion |
  Select-String 'Application Name'
```

I get an output like this:

```
@{DisplayName=Application Name; DisplayVersion=52.4.1521}
```

If this was on Unix, I could probably figure out a `sed` or `awk` command to extract the version number, but on Windows I don't even know where to begin. How do I get that version number out as the value of a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` produces a list of objects, so you should work with the properties of those objects. Filter the list via `Where-Object` for the object with the display name you're looking for, then expand the `DisplayVersion` property:

```
$regpath = 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
$version = Get-ItemProperty "$regpath\*" |
           Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq 'Application Name' } |
           Select-Object -Expand DisplayVersion
```

You can also have the filter do partial matches with wildcards

```
... | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like '*partial name*' } | ...
```

or regular expressions

```
... | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match 'expression' } | ...
```

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thank you.